# How to resolve ImageView padding issue inside HorizontalScrollView on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-scrollview

[image]

As shown in the image, I have tabs as in browser tabs. And I have padding between tab images to overlap on each other adjacent images. I need a particular image needs to be on top of adjacent images(image below) when the user touches it and also want to do the same through code.

[image]

I have a onTouchListener to the whole scrollview. It works fine with the below code when the user manually touches the image.

```
tab[id].bringToFront();
tabScrollView.invalidate();
```

If I do the same through code instead of manual user touch, the selected tab image goes to the right end since it uses bringToFront() method. Is there any way how I can bring it just on top of adjacent images?

Update:

I have already tried,

```
tab[id].performClick();
tab[id].performLongClick();
```

And also tried,

```
tab[id].setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener()); //my own listener
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime, 
                eventTime, 
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
                x, 
                y, 
                metaState
            );

// Dispatch touch event to view
tab[id].dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Both the methods mentioned above doesn't help. Do I need to provide any more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with,

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime, 
            eventTime, 
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
            x, 
            y, 
            metaState
        );

// Dispatch touch event to the view which contains all the images
tabScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```